# Invalid forEach()

Tags: php, pdo

I have a database that stores readings added by the user according to date, I want to display the readings on my HTML page according to the most recently added, So i modified my statement to look like this:

```
public function getElecReadings(){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT ElecReadingID, ElecUsage, DateAdded FROM elec_readings ORDER BY DESC WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "'");
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }
```

However, once i added the `ORDER BY`clause i seem to get the `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error on my HTML page where i echo out the values,

```
<?php
        foreach ($elec_readings as $elec_reading): ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $elec_reading['ElecUsage']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $elec_reading['DateAdded']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            ?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You are not fetching data from your result set!!

Comment: So what does `$elec_readings` contain?

Comment: Share output of $elec_readings by using print_r

Comment: `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT ElecReadingID, ElecUsage, DateAdded FROM elec_readings WHERE AccountNumber = '123456' ORDER BY DateAdded DESC ) `

Comment: @Saty That's not necessary, the `PDOStatement` class implementes `Traversable` so you can loop over it to get the results.

Comment: Thank you @jeroen for your information .I will keep this thing in my mind!!

Comment: @T91 I have rolled-back your edit as the answers will not make sense any more if you correct the mistakes in the question itself.

Comment: @jeroen Okay thanks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your SQL query is now bad. Order BY is AFTER the WHERE close

```
(SELECT ElecReadingID, ElecUsage, DateAdded FROM elec_readings WHERE [your_condition] ORDER BY [Your_Field] DESC|ASC ");
```

Foreach display error cause your SQL query fail, and `$elec_readings` is empty (or FALSE)

Comment: That seems to work but i want to Limit only the latest 3 added, when i add `LIMIT 3` then it displays 3 but not the last 3

Comment: @T91 You don't seem to be ordering by any field, check the code in the answer.

Comment: Edited my original post, this answered my question!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public function getElecReadings(){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT ElecReadingID, ElecUsage, DateAdded FROM elec_readings WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "' ORDER BY DESC");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}

<?php
    if (!empty($elec_readings)):
     foreach ($elec_readings as $elec_reading): ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $elec_reading['ElecUsage']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $elec_reading['DateAdded']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        ?php
    endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Nothing displays now, just an empty table

Comment: Your query returns nothing. You have some problem in your query.

Comment: It works when i add the `ORDER BY` after the `WHERE` clause

Comment: That's the rule. `ORDER BY` after the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `Warning` because your query is invalid, if you want to use ORDER BY along with WHERE clause than you need to follow this sequence:

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE .. ORDER BY ..
```

**Modified Query:**

```
$stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("
SELECT ElecReadingID, ElecUsage, DateAdded 
FROM elec_readings 
WHERE AccountNumber = '" . $_SESSION['user_session'] . "' 
ORDER BY ElecReadingID DESC");
```

Note that, You also need to specify the column which you need to change the order, in above example, i am using `ElecReadingID` column in `ORDER BY DESC`